# Singleton Pattern in Python create same variable two time in UML

Tags: python, singleton, pycharm

I creat a singleton pattern in Python, but if I crate an UML of this, I return a UML with two time the `__instance` variable in the Diagram.

But I have no clue, why this happens.

```
#Singleton
    __instance=None

    def __new__(cls):
        if HeatingStateOn.__instance is None:
             HeatingStateOn.__instance = object.__new__(cls)
        return HeatingStateOn.__instance
```

Why this happens and what is the mistake in my code?

[image]

***UPDATE***

I run the following unittest and the result is green.

```
 def test_heatingStateOn_singleton(self):
        a = HeatingStateOn()
        b = HeatingStateOn()
        self.assertEqual(a, b)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you let us know how did you create UML of the class? by what tools or command

Comment: I use the Diagramm functionality of Intelij PyCharm.

Comment: @michael-mammut Seems like a bug. You should open a bug in PyCharm's bug tracker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a tool issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your codes, and checked the id of the instance, there's only one __instance actually. Please check the following codes:

```
class HeatingStateOn:
    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if HeatingStateOn.__instance is None:
            HeatingStateOn.__instance = object.__new__(cls)
        return HeatingStateOn.__instance


a = HeatingStateOn()
b = HeatingStateOn()
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

id of a is same as the id of b, which means a and b share the same memory.

Comment: Hello, I wrote a unit test and add them to my Question. The test is green. That means that the singleton works.

Comment: but it does not explain, why `__instance` is two times on the list.

Comment: OP doesn't ask about the behavior of the code in run time. They ask about the IDE's behavior.